# For loop terminates earlier than expected when iterating over a text file

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, stack, java.util.scanner

I've been reading this book, [Algorithms by Sedgewick and Wayne](https://sedgewick.io/books/algorithms/), and this is one of the exercises given in chapter 1:

*1.3.4 Write a stack client Parentheses that reads in a text stream from standard input and uses a stack to determine whether its parentheses are properly balanced. For example, your program should print true for [()]{}{()()} and false for [(]).*

Now, my solution works when using a while loop (although it doesn't exactly do what was asked):

[Link to In.java](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/In.java.html)

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;

public class Parenthesis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        In input = new In("parenthesis.txt");
        LinkedListStack<String> stack = new LinkedListStack<>();

        while (!input.isEmpty()) {
            String s = input.readLine();
            
            if (s.equals("("))
                stack.push(s);
            else if (s.equals(")"))
                if (!stack.isEmpty())
                    stack.pop();
                else
                    stack.push(s);
        }

        if (stack.isEmpty())
            StdOut.println("Balanced");
        else
            StdOut.println("Unbalanced");
    }
}
```

But when I replace the while loop with a for loop, the loop terminates before reaching the last ")":

```
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In;
import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdOut;

public class Parenthesis {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        In input = new In("parenthesis.txt");
        LinkedListStack<String> stack = new LinkedListStack<>();

        for (String s = input.readLine(); !input.isEmpty(); s = input.readLine()) {
            if (s.equals("("))
                stack.push(s);
            else if (s.equals(")"))
                if (!stack.isEmpty())
                    stack.pop();
                else
                    stack.push(s);
        }
    
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            StdOut.println("Balanced");
        else
            StdOut.println("Unbalanced");
    }
}
```

I thought the for loop I used was just a compact version of the while loop, but clearly I'm doing something wrong. I've tried debugging the code over and over, but can't figure out why this happens.

P.S. if there is a more efficient approach for this problem, please do share it. Thanks!

Comment: You always read two lines in `for (String s = input.readLine(); !input.isEmpty(); s = input.readLine()) {`

Comment: What is `edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In`?

Comment: @Jens I suspected so, but I don't really know why. From what I understand, `String s = input.readLine()` initializes `s` to the first line,  `!input.isEmpty()` checks if the current line is empty, and the second `input.readLine()` updates `s` with the next line after every iteration. So it should iterate read all the lines...

Comment: @Queeg source code for the `In` class used here

Comment: @oresky Hard to say without knowing the implementation of IN. But I would suggest you to use a debugger to find out what is going on

Comment: @oresky Your assumption is wrong. `!input.isEmpty()` does not check if the current line is empty. It checks whether there is still data that can be obtained via `input.readLine()`. The current line is stored in `s`.

Comment: @Queeg Yes, and I think that the body is never executed because `s` is updated _before_ the condition is checked. When I tried stepping into the loop, first it opened `readLine()` and then `isEmpty()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because a for loop checks its termination condition after it performs an increment, and terminartes if it is false, the result of the `readLine` which moves the `In` to empty will never be used.

Run this code to see:

```
public class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        In in = new In();
        for (String s = in.readLine(); !in.isEmpty(); s = in.readLine()) {
            System.out.println("body");
        }
    }

}
class In {
    private int count = 0;
    public String readLine() {
        System.out.println("readLine " + count);
        return ""+count++;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        System.out.println("isEmpty " + count);
        return count > 2;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
readLine 0
isEmpty 1
body
readLine 1
isEmpty 2
body
readLine 2
isEmpty 3
```

See that `body` doesn't appear after the last `readLine`.

Another bug in your program is that `readLine` is called at least once -- even if the `In` is already empty.

If you really want to use a `for` loop, you can create an `Iterable` and use a foreach loop:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        In in = new In();
        for (String s: new InIterable(in)) {
            System.out.println("body " + s);
        }
    }

}

class InIterable implements Iterable<String> {
    private final In in;

    InIterable(In in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return !in.isEmpty();
            }

            @Override
            public String next() {
                return in.readLine();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the for loop check for the condition before incrementing?